# Encode cgi scripts UTF-8 or not?

Tags: perl, utf-8, cgi

I have been encoding all my website to UTF-8 after reading about the basics of encoding and character sets and all that stuff.
I have just uploaded a cgi script UTF-8 encoded. It reads data from an HTML form (also UTF-8) and I keep getting a 500 error.
I have even made an script just to say "OK" and it doesn't work. I mean, no reading from a form, no reading nothing, just printing a line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use utf8;
BEGIN {
    $| = 1;
    open (STDERR, ">&STDOUT");
    print qq~Content-type: text/html\n\n~;
}
print "ok";
```

I have moved the use "utf8;" below the BEGIN block and none is working. So, the 500 error says the script is not being read, as it if hadn't 755 permissions (it has).

So, my question is not about reading UTF8 data, but about running UTF8 encoded perl script.

Should I keep my scripts ANSI encoded (and work around reading the utf8 data from HTML forms)?

I have Perl 5.8 running on Apache on Linux. And... if I encode the script to Ansi, it works well (except for the reading of UTF-8 characters, but that's another story)

Comment: comment out your `open` line and see what happens.

Comment: There are no non-ASCII characters in your script, and UTF-8 is exactly equivalent to ASCII as long as there are no characters with codes above 127.  You say it works if you "encode the script to Ansi".  Exactly how did you change it to make it work?  In the code you posted, there's no need for a BEGIN block; deleting `BEGIN {` and `}` should make no difference.

Comment: Check the server's log file for the actual error. Saying you got a 500 error is useless.

Answer (score 4):

`use utf8` means only that your Perl source code is in UTF-8.  It has nothing to do with whether the script can process UTF-8 data from a form.

If your script stops working when you add the `use utf8;` line, then I see two possible problems:

1. There's something wrong with your Perl installation, so you get an error when it tries to load `utf8.pm`, or (more likely)
2. Your editor inserts a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) when you save a file as UTF-8.  The BOM interferes with the `#!` processing, so your script can't run.

Comment: Thanks to everyone.
As cjm says the very problem was the BOM. As long as I encoded 'without BOM' the script worked well. This was a little tricky for me to realize. I hope this little answer could help in the future to somebody else.

Comment: It might help others in the future even more if you mark it as "answer"